# AS3 - e:Event and byteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, events, arrays

I receive this error by running the function below.

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.utils::ByteArray@30e3fa1 to flash.events.Event.

```
uploadImage(e.currentTarget.byteArray)


function uploadImage(e:Event):void
{
var byteArrayAsString = Base64.encode(e.currentTarget.byteArray);
}
```

Does somebody knows what I need to change?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `ByteArray` to a function that only accepts an `Event`. Change it to `uploadImage(e)` to pass the entire event object. But, honestly, you might want to go back and review some language fundamentals. No offense, but it's pretty obvious whats wrong, if you even are vaguely aware of programming.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to AS3. Can you suggest some books or blogs that help me learn the fundamentals? What is most important to learn first?